# Problem with Mysite Sites feed

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, my-site, newsfeed, distributedcache

On a client's SP2013 O/P install we're having a problem with the 'Sites' feed on the `/personal/<user>/social/sites.aspx` page for user's Mysites.

The feed shows sites that are being explicitly followed by the user (i.e. that they've clicked Follow for), but according to the client the feed has always shown any sites the user was given access to via AD groups as well, but this doesn't seem to be happening now.

I've added all the service accounts to have full control on the User Profile Service app, but apart from that unsure where the settings for this are held - can't find much info on it, at least not in the sense of auto-updating based on permissions.

Only possibly related problem I can see is that the User Profile Service App User Cache Feed Repopulation job is failing pretty regularly when running on schedule for the two web servers, but runs OK manually for the app server (can't find a way to manually run it specifically for the webs). The error relates to a terminated connection to the cache cluster but I've checked the status of Distributed Cache and it all looks healthy - don't want to risk doing a remove/re-add on prod and booking a change for it would add at least another week to fixing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Only sites you've explicitly followed show in the feed. Being a member of them isn't enough.

Comment: Yeah, it's the bit above - wasn't sure what it was but worked out it's the Promoted Sites. Seems to be more of a problem with the audience compilation so closing this one and will ask another if it's a UPSA issue I can't resolve.

Comment: Issue seems to be with Promoted Sites... confusion over which bit was which!